# If the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ have the same $p$-adic absolute value, must $\left|\operatorname{tr}(A)^2\right|\le |\det(A)|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $A$ be an invertible $2\times2$ matrix over a complete nonarchimedean field $k$ - e.g., $k = \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Suppose its eigenvalues have the same absolute value (in $\overline{k}$). Must we have:
$$\left|\operatorname{tr}(A)\right|^2\le \det(A)?$$

(It's certainly true if we replace the right hand side with $4\det(A)$)

Comment: \text{tr} doesn't always behave the same as \operatorname{tr}: $$ \begin{align} & a \text{tr}(b) \\ \text{versus } & a\operatorname{tr}(b) \\  \\ & \text{tr} A \\ \text{versus } & \operatorname{tr} A  \end{align} $$ That's why \operatorname{tr} is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Then we have
$$ |\mathrm{tr}(A)|=|\lambda_1+\lambda_2|\leq \max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|\}=|\lambda_1|$$
since by hypothesis $|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2|$, hence
$$ |\mathrm{tr}(A)|^2\leq |\lambda_1|^2=|\lambda_1||\lambda_2|=|\lambda_1\lambda_2|=|\det(A)|$$
as desired.

Comment: Ah of course. I had forgotten about the ultrametric inequality >.<

Comment: @rtz: what about the converse?